# SQL query to find either current active date range, or last passed date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Given a date D, is there a way to find out the current active subscription or the most recent expired subscription for each user.

Here's the table structure

```
user_subscription(
    user_subscription_id PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id,
    subscription_start_date,
    subscription_end_date,
    user_subscription_count
)
```

Sample Data:

```
1   1   01-jan-2011     31-jan-2011     1
2   1   01-mar-2011     01-apr-2011     2
3   1   03-jun-2011     05-dec-2011     3
4   2   05-jan-2011     11-jan-2011     1
5   2   01-jun-2011     01-nov-2011     2
```

Example result for:

- `D = 15-jan-2011` would be row 1 for user 1 and row 4 for user 2.

I'm struggling to figure out a way to do this in SQL.

Currently I do a separate query for each user, but it's expensive to do it for thousands of users.

Any help/ideas are really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your current query ?

Comment: Do you have overlapping / inclusive periods?

Comment: @chanom-first I currently fetch all the subscriptions for a user using a SQL query, and then process then sequentially in Java.

Comment: @RogerWolf Nope, I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95688

```
DECLARE @D AS DATE='15-jan-2011'
;WITH CTE 
as
(   SELECT * 
    FROM user_subscription 
    WHERE (@D BETWEEN subscription_start_date and subscription_end_date) OR subscription_end_date <= @D 
),
CTE1
AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY subscription_end_date DESC) AS RN,*
   FROM CTE
)

SELECT * FROM CTE1 WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '20110115'

;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY subscription_start_date DESC)
    FROM user_subscription
    WHERE
        subscription_end_date <= @d 
)
SELECT
    user_subscription_id, user_id,subscription_start_date, subscription_end_date
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming subscriptions for each user ascend in time in accordance with `user_subscription_count` and there is only one thing being subscribed to, try:

```
select *
  from user_subscription s
 where user_subscription_count =
       (select max(x.user_subscription_count)
          from user_subscription x
         where x.user_id = s.user_id
           and x.subscription_start_date < @D)
```